# document.scrollTo does not work when running

Tags: javascript, html

So I am  trying to make a embed game on my website and I have this javascript code to scroll down when it is clicked but I do not know how to get it to work. :\

```html
<h3>
Need a Lift? <a href="javascript:document.scrollTo(5, 5)" >Click Here.</a>
</h3>
```

I also don't which to use, `window`, or `document`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scrollTo` is [a function on `window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo), [not `document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document).

```
<h3>
Need a Lift? <a href="javascript:window.scrollTo(5, 5)" >Click Here.</a>
</h3>
```

Comment: Thank you. I been trying to research, but at first I did ```window.scrollTo(5);```, but then I did ```document.scrollTo(5, 5);```, and then I did not go back to window.